# The bound of the largest eigenvalue of a symmetric positive definite matrix divided by its diagonal matix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix, $D$ is the diagnal matrix of A. The largest eigenvalue of $D^{-1}A $ is denoted by $\lambda$. Then what is the bouned of $\lambda$?

I only see the easy result $\lambda>0$, but I don't how how to get the upper bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nonzero eigenvalues of $D^{-1}A$ are the same as the nonzero eigenvalues
of $D^{-1/2} A D^{-1/2}$.  Note that this is a positive definite matrix with 
diagonal elements $1$.  The sum of the eigenvalues is the trace, which (if your matrices are $n \times n$) is $n$, and since all eigenvalues are nonnegative the largest must be less than $n$.  This is best possible, because the matrix with
all diagonal entries $1$ and all off-diagonal $1-\epsilon$ (with $0 < \epsilon < 1$) is positive definite with
largest eigenvalue $n - (n-1)\epsilon$.

Comment: By the way, Can you tell me how you calculate the biggest eigenvalue of the matrix you posted, I tried but so complicated.

Comment: Not at all complicated.  The eigenvector is all $1$'s.  The orthogonal complement of that is the eigenspace for $\epsilon$.